# What's the next step in resolving non-working touchscreen?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, touchscreen, i2c

The touchscreen on my dual-boot laptop doesn't work on Ubuntu. I've been looking around to what might be causing the problems and how to solve them but I've run into a dead end.

The hardware works because Windows has no problem with it.

The system registers(?) there is a touchscreen as can be seen on the output of `xinput list`

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System  id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN0501:00 04F3:3093 Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD User Facing: HD User Facing            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Where the *Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System* corresponds to the touchscreen.

Running `sudo lsinput` I can get more details on it:

```
/dev/input/event7
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x2386
   product : 0x3125
   version : 272
   name    : "Raydium Corporation Raydium Touc"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null)
```

But here the success ends. If I try extracting any data from it through `sudo cat /dev/input/event7` the output is empty.

These were all steps suggested by the page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Testing/Touch, but except for the next steps, of which I'm not sure what they mean:

> 5. Kernel support for touch and pen screens can be found in:
>
> - drivers/input/touchscreen
> - drivers/input/tablet
> - drivers/hid
>
> 6. Determine the firmware version and update appropriate hardware table:
>    N-Trig: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/NtrigFirmwareStatus

this page itself has "(TODO: Then what?)" exactly at the stage I get at.

Regarding drivers, I have managed to find only this page https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/input/touchscreen
which has a driver for *Raydium Touch* but only for the i2c bus, whereas my touchscreen is connected through BUS_USB

> raydium_i2c_ts.c   | Input: raydium_i2c_ts - use true and false for boolean values

I have been looking around questions about touchscreens and I've noticed some other people have complained about it with exactly the same touchscreen and USB bus, but with widely different laptops and versions of Ubuntu. (There were no answers there.)

**Is it simply the drivers missing? How can I check? Where could I find such drivers? Can updating Linux kernel help in any way? How come the screen appears on the input lists?**

**Would the i2c bus driver for this touchscreen work for the USB bus or is there any way of converting it?**

I would be grateful for any hints or speculations on which directions could I go to solve this issue or what could I look into. I am not too experienced yet on how does Linux handle these low-level things.

*Exact specs for reference*

- Acer Swift 5 SF514-53T
- Ubuntu 20.04.04 LTS  (*also 18.04.1 LTS*)
- Bios 1.03
- Kernel 4.15.0-45-generic

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get touchscreen working?